# If any field in array is not empty, display message - PHP / [POST] form

Tags: php, arrays, forms, post

I have a form with 25+ fields. I want to display a message if ANY of the fields in the array are NOT empty.

```
$customfields = array('q1', 'q2', 'q3', 'q4', 'q5', 'q6', 'q7', 'q8', 'q9', 'q10', 'q11', 'q12', 'q13', 'q14', 'q15', 'q16', 'q17', 'q18', 'q19', 'q20', 'q21', 'q22', 'q23', 'q24');
```

I've taken a look at similar SO questions for verifying that all fields are not empty, i.e.:

```
$error = false;
foreach($customfields as $field) {
  if (empty($_POST[$field])) {
    $error = true;
  }
}

if ($error) {
  echo "Here's an awesome message!";
} else {
  echo "None for you, Glen Coco.";
}
```

How do I do the opposite - display a message if ANY one or more than one fields in the array are not empty?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `if (!empty($_POST[$field]))` ?

Comment: check with `!empty()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the opposite comparison in the `if`:

```
$error = false;
foreach($customfields as $field) {
  if (!empty($_POST[$field])) {
    $error = true;
    break; // get out of foreach loop
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to take a look into the NOT operator.

You can just write this:

```
if (!empty($_POST[$field])) {
  //^ See here the NOT operator
    $error = true;
}
```

For more information see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php